# p4 remove old copies of submitted files

Tags: perforce

How do I remove old copies of edited/submitted p4 files: `edited_this_already.ext~`?

I can remove them via Unix command, but can p4 do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Open For Delete p4 delete what do you mean by 'old copies'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not in the depot under source control then Perforce doesn't know anything about the file so it can't delete it.

You're safe to use the OS commands to delete the files.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which editor you use, you can probably configure the editor so that it does not make these backup files. For example, with 'vim', use ':set nobackup' in your startup script (or, if you want Vim to make the backup files, but put them somewhere else, try ':set backupdir').

Comment: :set dir=<directory> specifically; if you use two trailing // (or \\), it will use full paths in the swap file name. (if you have two .gitignores open; but they exist in different directories; the backup files won't collide)